# Can a pdf splitter on appengine be built?

Tags: google-app-engine

Would it be technically possible to build a pdf splitter on appengine or is there some part of it that couldn't be done? I was thinking of a function where you just upload the pdf file, choose which pages you want and the output is e.g. one chapter from a book and this can be done online. I think it can be a good service but I don't know whether it is technically feasible or whether the best choice first this would be Java, Python, PHP or Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see why not. Splitting a PDF should be possible in all 4 languages so it's up to you what you pick. I know that Python performs faster than Java. PHP doesn't sound like a good fit for me and Go isn't that widely used.

I'd go with Python. There is also a Python library that allows you to split a PDF.